# admin page shows Front controller reached 100 router match iterations in magento 2

Tags: magento2

my magento 2 site front end has no problem. 
but when i open admin login page it will shows

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations
#0 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#6 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#17 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#18 {main}
```

Comment: Let me know have u installed any new module ?

Comment: recently adding ssl to my site